How to redirect all GRPC streams of a given GRPC client to a single Kubernetes pod
Current Deployment :
GRPC client( with multiple streams) -> Nginx Reverse Proxy(Nginx Ingress Controller) -> Multiple GRPC server pod running in Kubernetes.
We need to terminate the all GRPC stream from single client on  a single Kubernetes pod.
Tried to solve using the  below approach.

Defined a custom GRPC  header using  Metadata concept  for each GRPC client.
 GrpcClient 1 -> client_id : 101 GrpcClient 2 -> client_id : 102 GrpcClient 3 -> client_id : 103

Used nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-hash-by  annotation in ingress configuration to map streams from specific client to specific pods.
 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-hash-by : $client_id
GrpcClient1,GrpcClient2,GrpcClient3 -> Nginx Reverse Proxy(Nginx Ingress Controller) -> GrpcServerPos1,GrpcServerPod2,GrpcServerPod3
But after this I am seeing an unexpected behaviour of termination of all client   to just a single GRPC server pod.
All GRPC client(GrpcClient1, GrpcClient2, GrpcClient3)  connected to  GrpcServerPod3.
The load distribution across pod is not happening.


Can you please let me know “What is the best way to to redirect  all GRPC streams of  a given  GRPC client  to a single Kubernetes pod?”
